# Header not allowed on the server?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, http-headers

I have a simple API in Laravel. The routes file is like so:

```
<?php

Route::resource('airports', 'AirportController');

Route::resource('flights', 'FlightController');

Route::resource('reservations', 'ReservationController');

Route::get('auth', 'AuthController@index');
Route::post('auth', 'AuthController@store');
Route::delete('auth', 'AuthController@destroy');
```

The filter's file has a custom filter added like so:

```
Route::filter('auth_token', function()
{
    $auth_token = Request::header('Authorization');

    if(!AuthToken::where('auth_token', '=', $auth_token)->first()){
        return Response::json([], 401);
    }
});
```

All the resources need to pass before the `auth_token` filter. Now this works great on my local machine but as soon as I try it on my server, everything is unauthorized, even if I pass a valid token. The problem I figured by `dd($auth_token)` in my custom filter is that it is returning null which means that my server is not accepting the header for some reason.

My .htaccess file looks like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
</IfModule>
```

I am using Postman REST client to test my application. There is only one user in the system with email 'admin@admin.com' and password 'admin12345'. You can `POST` these details to the `/auth` route and get an access token granted which can then be used to fetch other resources in the system.

The application is hosted [here](http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the routes might be an issue. try inverting like this and see if it works ...

```
Route::get('auth', 'AuthController@index');
Route::post('auth', 'AuthController@store');
Route::delete('auth', 'AuthController@destroy');

Route::resource('airports', 'AirportController');
Route::resource('flights', 'FlightController');
Route::resource('reservations', 'ReservationController');
```